# 1.9.2 image issue - have buttons, uploads successfully, does not attach to product

Tags: magento-1.9, adminhtml, image-upload

I have the upload buttons, the file uploads successfully, but it does not attach to product

Magento 1.9.2.4

I have done the following

Ensure that the app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/media folder exists and that there are 2 files within it.

```
editor.phtml
uploader.phtml
```

Ensure that the skin/adminhtml/default/default/media folder exists and that there are 3 files within it.

```
flex.swf
uploader.swf
uploaderSingle.swf
```

I have the "browse files" and "upload files" buttons, and I can browse files, and when I upload the notice goes green with success message.

Media directory, all subfolders are chmod to 777

I get the following json result

```
{
  "name":"screenshot.png",
  "type":"application/octet-stream",
  "tmp_name":"/tmp/phpsfaygg",
  "error":0,
  "size":59074,
  "path":"/www/domain.com/media/tmp/catalog/product",
  "file":"/s/c/screenshot_3.png.tmp",
  "url":"https://www.domain.com/media/tmp/catalog/product/s/c/screenshot_3.png",
  "cookie": {
    "name":"adminhtml",
    "value":"8dci943bhj8e9941oskmf1ahi1",
    "lifetime":"3600",
    "path":"/",
    "domain":"www.domain.com"
  }
}
```

When I go to the "url" location the file is there, so it has uploaded successfully, but it is not attaching to the product

**Side note**
I do not have the upload buttons on CMS pages, so cannot test that, I also need assistance with that

Answer (score 0):

fixed

uploaded all files from a clean copy of 1.9.2.4

```
/app/code/core/Mage/adminhtml/
/app/code/core/Zend/
/app/design/adminhtml/
/js/
/lib/
/skin/adminhtml/
```

not sure which file was corrupted, but I figured anything with adminhtml should be safe to transplant and the /js/ /lib/ folders should be safe bets as well